# getLocalRow returning old value in jqgrid adjacency tree model

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using JqGrid's `addRowData` method to add the rows from the server onto the grid.

If I use the `getLocalRow` method, the values I see are the old ones and not the updated values. But if I see the element the values are updated, why this is happening?

The following is the colmodel properties

```
        url  :  '/pots/getTasks.htm?id='+projectId,
        datatype  :  'json',
        mtype  :  'GET',
        colNames  : userColNames ,
        colModel  :  userColModel,
        pager: '#divTaskPager',
        treeGridModel:'adjacency',
        treeGrid: true,
        cellEdit: true,
        sortable: false,
        gridview:true,
        loadui:'block',


oGrid.addRowData(data.id, data, 'first' );
```

`data` is the data the I get from the server and it is in the format {"col1":"value1","col2":"value2"...}

```
nIndex = oGrid.getInd( data.id );
if( nIndex != 1 )
{
    oGrid.addRowData(data.id, data, 'after' , arrayDataIDs[ nIndex-2 ] );
    var obj = oGrid.getLocalRow(data.id);
    oGrid.setCell(data.id, 'listTaskAssignment', ormattedResources,'','',true);
    if( data.isCompleted == true || data.isCompleted == "true" )
    {        
        pots.utility.changeEditable($("#tree"),true,data.id);                               $('#'+parseInt(data.id)+' > [aria-describedby="tree_cb"]').children().attr('checked',false).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
else
{
    oGrid.addRowData(data.id, data, 'first' );
    oGrid.setCell(data.id, 'listTaskAssignment', formattedResources,'','',true);
    if( data.isCompleted == true || data.isCompleted == "true" )
    {
        pots.utility.changeEditable($("#tree"),true,data.id);
        $('#'+parseInt(data.id)+' > [aria-describedby="tree_cb"]').children().attr('checked',false).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear fr me why you use `addRowData` method to add the data to the TreeGrid which you get **from the server**. In any way the filling of the TreeGrid is your main problem. So you should include the code which you use in your question.

Comment: what is problem in using addRowData for adding rows to tree grid? please explain

Comment: getRowData is giving me the updated row but not getLocalRow!!! and if I see the row using mozilla firebug I see the updated row,I think the local array is not updated how to update the local array?

Comment: First of all `addRowData` is *the most slow method which I know* to fill the grid. Moreover I see no sense in calling it in case of loading the data *from the server*. jqGrid can do this directly, and the implementation will be more simple and more quickly. You should append your question with the code which you use. It is also important to know which version of jqGrid you use.

Comment: sorry "loading the data from the server" means on ajax call getting some rows that are updated by other users on server and adding to the grid,these rows may be already present in the grid so I need to update them. If not addRowData which other method I can use?

Comment: you should describe the problem which you have more detailed in the main text of your question. If the text in comments will be longer as the text of the question, than you wrote the question not clear enough. You can't just use `addRowData` if the data could already exist in the grid. Depend on the number of rows which need be updated and the number of existing rows in the grid it could be more effective either to use `addRowData` or `setRowData` together with `getLocalRow` or to reload the full grid contain. I can repeat only that you should include more full code which you use.

Comment: If you want I can just answer on your direct question. It will be easy enough, but I asked you many question, because I suppose that you chosen not the good way in your current implementation.

Comment: I added the code please gothrough.

Comment: Sorry, but the code which you posted make more questions as get answers. Why you use `setCell` after `addRowData`? It makes the code event more slowly. You get `var obj = oGrid.getLocalRow(data.id)`, but don't use it. You don't defined `pots.utility.changeEditable`  and it's unclear whether `$("#tree")` is the same as `oGrid` or it's *another* TreeGrid. Moreover in case of TreeGrid it's very important the place where you add the node. You should add it *after it's parent*. It's unclear from your current code. Do you need to add new root node only?

Comment: I have a custom field whose value is an object from the server so I need to parse and make it in to string and add to that column so I'm using setCell,changeEditable is a method  wihich changes the editality of columns based on some condition and oGrid and $("#tree") both are same

Comment: You should first change the array with data which you add and then call only `addRowData` without `setCell`. You should understand that every change of any element on the page will can change the position of **all other elements on the page** or at least follow to reflow of the page. Even reflow is expansive enough (see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) for example). So reloading of the whole grid with respect of assignment of `innerHTML` property of grid can be quickly as change of some cells of the grid. Moreover you should at least use `addChildNode`: see my answer

Comment: I see that you almost not use voting. Probably you don't know [the common rule](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." If you just "accept" the answer without voting you find the answer not really helpful, but you want close the discussion (close your question). You have right to vote about 30 questions or answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). *If you want help other to find the answer or the question you should vote it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods `addRowData`, `setRowData` and `setCell` update local data only for the case `datatype: 'local'`. You use `datatype: 'json'` so the `data` and `_index` parameters which hold local data used by TreeGrid will be **not** updated automatically ba the functions. I don't recommend you to use low-level function like `addRowData` to fill grid and especially TreeGrid. If you do need to use the functions in your special case you have to update `data` and `_index` manually after the usage of `addRowData`, `setRowData` or `setCell`. The method `getLocalRow` will get you the data which represent the existing row if any exist. You can just update the data after the usage of `setRowData` or `setCell`. If no row exist you can add the data to the TreeGrid using `addChildNode` method which add not only the data to the TreeGrid, but also update the internal parameters `data` and `_index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
oGrid.setGridParam({"datatype":"local"});
oGrid.addRowData(data.id, data, 'after' , arrayDataIDs[ nIndex-2 ] );
oGrid.setGridParam({"datatype":"json"});
```

I found that I can update the local array by changing the grid property datatype to local and adding a row and then setting the datatype back to json